# Python3 get process base-address from PID

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory-address, pywin32

I am trying to get the base-address of a process in Windows (64-bit), with Python3, assuming to know the PID.
I looked over all questions here on stack, but the solutions are old/not working.

I assume to have the PID of the process in a variable called pid.

One of the many pieces of code I tried is

```
PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = 0x1F0FFF
processHandle = win32api.OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, pid)
modules = win32process.EnumProcessModules(processHandle)
fileName = win32process.GetModuleFileNameEx(processHandle, modules[0])
base_address = win32api.GetModuleHandle(fileName)
processHandle.close()
```

But I get error on GetModuleHandle: 'Impossible to find the specified module'.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [[MS.Docs]: GetModuleHandleW function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulehandlew) (**emphasis** is mine):

> Retrieves a module handle for the specified module. **The module must have been loaded by the calling process**.

That means that it will work fine for the current process, but for any other one you'd get *Undefined Behavior*, because you try retrieving:

1. The *.dll* (or *.exe*) name from the other process (*GetModuleFileNameEx* call)
2. The handle for the name at previous step (*GetModuleHandle* call) **but in the current process** (if loaded), which makes no sense

<s>Although there's no clear documentation on this topic (or at least I couldn't find any)</s>, the handle **is** the base address. This is a principle that you also rely on (calling *GetModuleHandle*), but you can use the values returned by *EnumProcessModules* directly (look at the example below, the values are the same).

If you want to be rigorous, you could use [[MS.Docs]: GetModuleInformation function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-getmoduleinformation). Unfortunately, that's not exported by *PyWin32*, and an alternative is using [[Python 3.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes).

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import win32api as wapi
import win32process as wproc
import win32con as wcon
import ctypes as ct
from ctypes import wintypes as wt
import traceback as tb


class MODULEINFO(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("lpBaseOfDll", ct.c_void_p),
        ("SizeOfImage", wt.DWORD),
        ("EntryPoint", ct.c_void_p),
    ]

get_module_information_func_name = "GetModuleInformation"
GetModuleInformation = getattr(ct.WinDLL("kernel32"), get_module_information_func_name, getattr(ct.WinDLL("psapi"), get_module_information_func_name))
GetModuleInformation.argtypes = [wt.HANDLE, wt.HMODULE, ct.POINTER(MODULEINFO)]
GetModuleInformation.restype = wt.BOOL


def get_base_address_original(process_handle, module_handle):
    module_file_name = wproc.GetModuleFileNameEx(process_handle, module_handle)
    print("    File for module {0:d}: {1:s}".format(module_handle, module_file_name))
    module_base_address = wapi.GetModuleHandle(module_file_name)
    return module_base_address


def get_base_address_new(process_handle, module_handle):
    module_info = MODULEINFO()
    res = GetModuleInformation(process_handle.handle, module_handle, ct.byref(module_info))
    print("    Result: {0:}, Base: {1:d}, Size: {2:d}".format(res, module_info.lpBaseOfDll, module_info.SizeOfImage))
    if not res:
        print("    {0:s} failed: {1:d}".format(get_module_information_func_name, getattr(ct.WinDLL("kernel32"), "GetLastError")()))
    return module_info.lpBaseOfDll


def main(*argv):
    pid = int(argv[0]) if argv and argv[0].isdecimal() else wapi.GetCurrentProcessId()
    print("Working on pid {0:d}".format(pid))
    process_handle = wapi.OpenProcess(wcon.PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, pid)
    print("Process handle: {0:d}".format(process_handle.handle))
    module_handles = wproc.EnumProcessModules(process_handle)
    print("Loaded modules: {0:}".format(module_handles))
    module_index = 0  # 0 - the executable itself
    module_handle = module_handles[module_index]
    get_base_address_funcs = [
        #get_base_address_original,  # Original behavior moved in a function
        get_base_address_new,
    ]
    for get_base_address in get_base_address_funcs:
        print("\nAttempting {0:s}".format(get_base_address.__name__))
        try:
            module_base_address = get_base_address(process_handle, module_handle)
            print("    Base address: 0x{0:016X} ({1:d})".format(module_base_address, module_base_address))
        except:
            tb.print_exc()
    process_handle.close()
    #input("\nPress ENTER to exit> ")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {0:s} {1:d}bit on {2:s}\n".format(" ".join(item.strip() for item in sys.version.split("\n")), 64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q059610466>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.07.06_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.7.6 (tags/v3.7.6:43364a7ae0, Dec 19 2019, 00:42:30) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
>
> Working on pid 59608
> Process handle: 452
> Loaded modules: (140696816713728, 140714582343680, 140714572513280, 140714535354368, 140714547544064, 140713592946688, 140714443341824, 140714557898752, 140714556325888, 140714550362112, 140714414964736, 140714562486272, 140714532798464, 140714555473920, 140714548592640, 140714533322752, 140714531946496, 140714553769984, 140714555670528, 140714558750720, 140714581426176, 140714556129280, 140714546036736, 140714518052864, 140714532601856, 140714524737536, 140714210361344, 1797128192, 140714574151680, 140714535026688, 140714557046784, 140714538172416, 140714531291136, 140714530963456, 140714530766848, 140714530832384, 1796931584, 140714561044480, 140714573299712, 140714215014400, 140714529849344, 1798438912, 140714559995904, 140714167042048)
>
> Attempting get_base_address_new
>     Result: 1, Base: 140696816713728, Size: 110592
>     Base address: 0x00007FF687C80000 (140696816713728)
>
> Done.
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q059610466>:: Attempting to run with Task Manager pid
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q059610466>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.07.06_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py 22784
> Python 3.7.6 (tags/v3.7.6:43364a7ae0, Dec 19 2019, 00:42:30) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
>
> Working on pid 22784
> Process handle: 480
> Loaded modules: (140699900903424, 140714582343680, 140714572513280, 140714535354368, 140714547544064, 140714573299712, 140714531946496, 140714550362112, 140714562486272, 140714532798464, 140714530963456, 140714530766848, 140714556981248, 140714557898752, 140714556325888, 140714555473920, 140714365222912, 140714548592640, 140714496753664, 140714533322752, 140714553769984, 140714574151680, 140714535026688, 140714557046784, 140714538172416, 140714581426176, 140714558750720, 140714531291136, 140714530832384, 140714546036736, 140714444521472, 140714567467008, 140714532601856, 140714468966400, 140714452385792, 140714267115520, 140714510843904, 140714478731264, 140713698263040, 140714510254080, 140714556129280, 140714565435392, 140714110091264, 140714491379712, 140714455007232, 140714514382848, 140714459529216, 140714281140224, 140714370859008, 140714471260160, 140714566746112, 140713839362048, 140714555670528, 140714171695104, 140714508615680, 140714514841600, 140714029154304, 140714036625408, 140714329636864, 140714447011840, 140714434691072, 140714470866944, 140714561044480, 140714520870912, 140714469883904, 140714494787584, 140714293592064, 140713999335424, 140714400743424, 140714497605632, 140714502193152, 140714197254144, 140714415030272, 140714035576832, 140714065854464, 140714513006592, 140714529652736, 140714512809984, 140714495049728, 140714038657024, 140714371448832, 140714421911552, 140714325966848, 140714196074496, 140714057924608, 140714058317824, 140714064281600, 140714058121216, 140714519756800, 140714327539712, 140714311614464, 140714501079040, 140714546167808, 140714531422208, 140714531553280, 140714557767680, 140714518052864, 140714524737536, 140714167631872, 140714528669696, 140714331865088, 140714310369280, 140714310238208, 140714520018944, 140714458939392, 2018133999616, 140714401988608, 2018141863936, 140714514644992, 140714454810624, 140714294640640)
>
> Attempting get_base_address_new
>     Result: 1, Base: 140699900903424, Size: 1105920
>     Base address: 0x00007FF73F9D0000 (140699900903424)
>
> Done.
> ```

---

#### Update *#0*

According to [[MS.Docs]: MODULEINFO structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/ns-psapi-moduleinfo) (**Remarks** section, **emphasis** still mine):

> **The load address of a module is the same as the *HMODULE* value.**

So, things seem to be pretty straightforward.

*code01.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import win32api as wapi
import win32process as wproc
import win32con as wcon


def main(*argv):
    pid = int(argv[0]) if argv and argv[0].isdecimal() else wapi.GetCurrentProcessId()
    print("Working on pid {0:d}".format(pid))
    process_handle = wapi.OpenProcess(wcon.PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, pid)
    print("  Process handle: {0:d}".format(process_handle.handle))
    module_handles = wproc.EnumProcessModules(process_handle)
    module_handles_count = len(module_handles)
    print("  Loaded modules count: {0:d}".format(module_handles_count))
    module_index = 0  # 0 - the executable itself
    if module_index > module_handles_count:
        module_index = 0
    module_handle = module_handles[module_index]
    module_file_name = wproc.GetModuleFileNameEx(process_handle, module_handle)
    print("  File [{0:s}] (index {1:d}) is loaded at address 0x{2:016X} ({3:d})".format(module_file_name, module_index, module_handle, module_handle))
    process_handle.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {0:s} {1:d}bit on {2:s}\n".format(" ".join(item.strip() for item in sys.version.split("\n")), 64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q059610466>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.07.06_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code01.py
> Python 3.7.6 (tags/v3.7.6:43364a7ae0, Dec 19 2019, 00:42:30) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
>
> Working on pid 7184
>   Process handle: 456
>   Loaded modules count: 43
>   File [e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.07.06_test0\Scripts\python.exe] (index 0) is loaded at address 0x00007FF687C80000 (140696816713728)
>
> Done.
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q059610466>:: Attempting to run with Task Manager pid
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q059610466>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.07.06_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code01.py 22784
> Python 3.7.6 (tags/v3.7.6:43364a7ae0, Dec 19 2019, 00:42:30) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
>
> Working on pid 22784
>   Process handle: 624
>   Loaded modules count: 111
>   File [C:\WINDOWS\system32\taskmgr.exe] (index 0) is loaded at address 0x00007FF73F9D0000 (140699900903424)
>
> Done.
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it on my target process. It find the module file name correctly, but it does not print any address.
So i tried to remove the try-catch to see the error and it is the same error: 'Impossible to find the specified module'.

Comment: You don't need to find the file name anymore. You already have the base address returned by *EnumProcessModules*. The error you mention isn't known to me. What's the error number? Also maybe you need to launch python from an elevated *cmd* window ("*Run as administrator*").

Comment: "You don't need to find the file name anymore. You already have the base address returned by EnumProcessModules." I know, it was just to say.
I already launch che cmd window ad admin.
The exact error is: "pywintypes.error: (126, 'GetModuleHandle', 'The specified module could not be found')".

Comment: That's what I said. *get\_base\_address\_original* for another process is wrong. Comment the line `get_base_address_original,` in *main*. How does the other function doing? *BTW*: "*The specified module could not be found*"  is **totally different** than "*Impossible to find the specified module*".

Comment: The get_base_address_new function returns None. The local variable res (given by GetModuleInformation) is printed as 0.

Comment: I modified the code to remove the original thing, and add some more output. But I can't reproduce the behavior. It works.

Comment: Anyway thank you for your time. I thumb up your answer, but I cannot say that the problem is solved. It looks like there are some processes for which GetModuleInformation does not get information.

Comment: I modified the script to a much lighter variant. Check if it works out.

Comment: Glad to hear that! :)