# ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: TypeError: Don't know how to convert parameter 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, ctypes, pywin32

my code..

```
import ctypes
import win32security

h_token = win32security.OpenProcessToken(ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetCurrentProcess(), win32security.TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS)

lpApplicationName = ctypes.c_wchar_p(rf"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe")
lpCommandLine = ctypes.c_wchar_p("")
dwCreationFlags = 0x00000010
lpEnvironment = None
lpProcessAttributes = None
lpThreadAttributes = None
bInheritHandles = False

ctypes.windll.advapi32.CreateProcessWithTokenW(h_token, 0, lpApplicationName, lpCommandLine, dwCreationFlags, lpEnvironment, None, lpProcessAttributes, lpThreadAttributes, bInheritHandles)
```

my output...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testx.py", line 96, in <module>
    ctypes.windll.advapi32.CreateProcessWithTokenW(h_token, 0, lpApplicationName, lpCommandLine, dwCreationFlags, lpEnvironment, None, lpProcessAttributes, lpThreadAttributes, bInheritHandles)
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: TypeError: Don't know how to convert parameter 1
```

how i can fix it? what i'm doing wrong?, thanks for read and help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a good idea to mix libraries / tools / frameworks, when things can be done in one of them. In this case:

- [[GitHub]: mhammond/pywin32 - Python for Windows (pywin32) Extensions](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32) is a *Python* wrapper over *WinAPI*s. Documentation (*WiP*) can be found at [[GitHub.MHammond]: Python for Win32 Extensions Help](https://mhammond.github.io/pywin32) (or [[ME.TimGolden]: Python for Win32 Extensions Help](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/contents.html))
- [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes)

At 1<sup>st</sup> glance, this situation seems to be one of the exceptions, as *CreateProcessWithTokenW* is not wrapped by *PyWin32*.

I played a bit with your code after fixing some errors:

- Pass `h_token.handle` to *CreateProcessWithTokenW*
- Fix ***U**ndefined **B**ehavior* (check [[SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546) for a common pitfall when working with *CTypes* (calling functions))

but I couldn't get it to work (got *ERROR_TOKEN_ALREADY_IN_USE*). Note that I didn't spend much time investigating (adjusting the token privileges, ...), because I paid more attention to what [[MS.Learn]: CreateProcessWithTokenW function (winbase.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createprocesswithtokenw) states:

> The process that calls **CreateProcessWithTokenW** must have the SE_IMPERSONATE_NAME privilege. If this function fails with ERROR_PRIVILEGE_NOT_HELD (1314), use the [CreateProcessAsUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessasusera) or [CreateProcessWithLogonW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createprocesswithlogonw) function instead.

*code00.py*:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

import win32api as wapi
import win32con as wcon
import win32process as wproc
import win32security as wsec


def main(*argv):
    token = wsec.OpenProcessToken(wproc.GetCurrentProcess(), wsec.TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS)
    #print(wsec.GetTokenInformation(token, wsec.TokenType))
    app_name = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe"
    creation_flags = wcon.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE
    si = wproc.STARTUPINFO()

    hproc, hthr, pid, tid = wproc.CreateProcessAsUser(token, app_name, None,
        None, None, 0, creation_flags,
        None, None, si)

    print("New PId: {:d}".format(pid))
    wapi.CloseHandle(token)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q075358233]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.10_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ./code00.py
> Python 3.10.9 (tags/v3.10.9:1dd9be6, Dec  6 2022, 20:01:21) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> New PId: 20512
>
> Done.
> ```

And **a new *Cmd* window popped up**. Note that my user has full administrative (God like) privileges.

Similar situations:

- [[SO]: Get the title of a window of another program using the process name (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31280850/4788546)
- [[SO]: Python3 get process base-address from PID (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59627372/4788546)

Answer (score 0):

The token returned by `win32security.OpenProcessToken` is a `PyHANDLE` object.  Use `int(h_token)` to get a value that `ctypes` will accept.  Note that you should set the `.argtypes` and `.restype` of a `ctypes` function or parameters and return value may not convert properly from Python to C.